# How to remove some keyboard layout in Windows 10 using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-layout, windows-10-v1709

I am curious as to how does one remove a keyboard layout in Windows 10 Professional using PowerShell?

Comment: @Ramhound See my answer for the easy approach :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How does one remove a keyboard layout in Windows 10 Pro using PowerShell?

You can use [Set-WinUserLanguageList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps).

> Sometimes I need to type in German or in Russian. Often enough – every
>   week I type something. Meanwhile, it bugs me to find the right layout
>   every time.
>
> And since I now prefer PowerShell to cmd.exe, I had a thought – I
>   should add these layouts as I need them. So, now I have two files:
>
> addDe.ps1:
>
> ```
> $1 = Get-WinUserLanguageList
> $1.Add('de-DE')
> Set-WinUserLanguageList $1 -Force
> ```
>
> remDe.ps1:
>
> ```
> $1 = Get-WinUserLanguageList
> $1.RemoveAll( { $args[0].LanguageTag -clike 'de*' } )
> Set-WinUserLanguageList $1 -Force
> ```

Source [Adding/removing keyboard layouts with PowerShell](https://modosansreves-coding.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/addingremoving-keyboard-layouts-with.html)

---

#### Further Reading

[Set-WinUserLanguageList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps)

Comment: If I understand correctly, this trick removes *both* the preferred display language and the associated keyboard layouts/IMEs, correct?