# How do I remove this from my windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows-10

Hi can someone help me clearing this language from my computer? That ENG language. I tried everything but nothing works.

https://prnt.sc/smimag

This is my language configuration on preferences.
Sorry for being in portuguese, but as you can see, I only have portuguese but on the task bar it has english too!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51cd.png

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: I posted the images, but they did not go to the post, i don't know why!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke?rq=1) question

Comment: What is the preload? I don't understand what I have to do!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically adding keyboard layouts (i.e. US keyboard)](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke)

Comment: Delete the English keyboard from the control panel

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with Powershell

```
$1 = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$1.RemoveAll( { $args[0].LanguageTag -clike 'de*' } )
Set-WinUserLanguageList $1 -Force
```

I copied it from here: [1297069](https://superuser.com/questions/1297069/how-to-remove-some-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10-using-powershell)

**Update from 2020-05-28**:

Start a powershell terminal as admin. Add Portuguese as your only language.

*Powershell*

`Set-WinUserLanguageList -Force 'pt-pt'`

With the command `Get-WinUserLanguageList` you get your current languages / keyboard layouts

*Registry*

I found on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41100072/10655742) also an answer. The way over the registry `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload` works quiet well.

Comment: You really should have flagged this question as a duplicate.  You didn't even modify the command to remove the proper keyboard layout for the author fo this question.

Comment: In the registery I have 1 and Predefinition what do I have to do?