# How can I get rid of a given keyboard layout

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout

After I've installed Windows 11, I have configured two keyboard layouts: US-english and CH-German with the following Powershell commands:

```
$preferredLanguages = new-winUserLanguageList 'en-US'
$preferredLanguages.add('de-CH')
set-winUserLanguageList -force $preferredLanguages
```

This worked as intended for several months - until Windows added, for no reason apparent to me, German (Switzerland) US (the second item in the picture below).

The link "More Keyboard settings" promises to fix this, but I am, frankly, overwhelmed with all the options presented when clicking it and I am wondering why it is not possible to just easily remove the superfluous item from the list.

When I execute the same Powershell snippet again, nothing changes.

[image: keyboard layout]

Comment: Does https://superuser.com/questions/1297069/how-to-remove-some-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10-using-powershell answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a keyboard layout in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10). This should also apply to Windows 11.

Comment: Yes, it hinted at the right direction although I have come to the conclusion that every answer seems to have a different layout of settings. Unfortunately, there was no way that showed how I could do that in PowerShell. I have voted to close my question / but apparently, the vote is gone.